# How to download and upload Sitecore media Library image programmatically?

Tags: c#, sitecore

I need to compress the size of Sitecore media item (image).

How can I programmatically read the media item and compress the image and then upload back to Sitecore media library using c#?

Comment: Are you aware that Sitecore can resize images on the fly? [**See this article.**](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/05/media-options-and-query-string-parameters-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx)

Comment: Is this related to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160764/sitecore-clone-sitecore-media-library-image-folder)? What do you mean about compress, do you mean optimize images?

Comment: @jammykam : yes this related to previous question

Comment: So what are you trying to do when you saying "compress the image"?

Comment: @jammykam : in sitecore i have two field one for selecting preview image and another one for selecting original images. currently both are referring original image. So I planned to write a c# code, to get the image location from the field and clone that into another folder called preview and reduce the size of image. for example if the image size 1000*600px then clone image should be 100*height

Comment: @ESWARANM What is the reason for not resizing with query parameters on the fly?